# res.success back to frontend from a Node.Js/Express app

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, form-post

I'm using AJAX in my app and at the frontend I have

```
$.post('/post', $("#submitform").serialize())
                .done(function(res) {
                    //3. Receive the server response, no need to emit an event
                    if (res.success) {
                        //4. Show the updated text
                        console.log('success');
                    }
                    else {
                        alert(res.error);
                    }})
                .fail(function(res) {
                    alert("Server Error: " + res.status + " " + res.statusText);
                });



        return false;
});
```

I'm sending back from my Node.Js/Express app route:

```
res.send(statement);
```

However, `res.success` doesn't get triggered and instead I go into `alert(res.error)` although the process performs fine at the backend.

What am I doing wrong? Shall I send something else from the backend of my app, like `res.success`?

Thank you!

Comment: What is your `res` object, has it a `success` property ? Maybe that it's just the data from the server.

Comment: Actually yes it's it data from the server, so what's the best way to receive this data and see if it was the data that indicate everything worked well?

Comment: Does `.done()` means that the request has been successful ? If yes, you don't need `res.success`

Comment: Maybe.... How do I check what it means?

Comment: If an error occurs in the server, you can still use `res.status(500).send('Label')`

Comment: Thanks! And how do I receive the res.send(statement) into my frontend?

Comment: If you specify `res.send({a: "b"})` in express; In the frontend, `res` will be equals to `{a: "b"}`

Comment: @Magador you were right! do you want to post it as an answer, so I can accept it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since, you are using ExpressJS with NodeJS on your server, you can send a error status code with the server when the HTTP request is not correct:

```
res.status(400).send('Bad Request')
```

In your client script which use the [jQuery Deferred Object](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/):

- `deferred.done()` is triggered when your [HTTP request is a success](http://www.wikiwand.com/en/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#/2xx_Success);
- `deferred.fail()` is triggered if there is a [client](http://www.wikiwand.com/en/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#/4xx_Client_Error) or [server](http://www.wikiwand.com/en/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#/5xx_Server_Error) error;

So you should use as your code:

```
$.post('/post', $("#submitform").serialize())
    .done(function(res) {
        // Receive the successful server response
        console.log('success');
    })
    .fail(function(res) {
        // Receive the error server response
        alert("Error: " + res.status + " " + res.statusText);
    });
```